# Ruby: Prioritising certain regex matches over others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

At the moment I have a regex that looks like this:

```
(?<country>United States): (?<dial_number>\+1([ ]*[()\d\-\.]+)+)|(?<country>Australia): (?<dial_number>\+61([ ]*[()\d\-\.]+)+)|(?<country>Canada): (?<dial_number>\+1([ ]*[()\d\-\.]+)+)|(?<country>United Kingdom): (?<dial_number>\+44([ ]*[()\d\-\.]+)+)|(?<country>New Zealand): (?<dial_number>\+64([ ]*[()\d\-\.]+)+)
```

And a string that looks like this (fake numbers):

```
Test Meeting 
Mon, Jan 15, 2018 10:00 AM - 5:00 PM AEST 

Please join my meeting from your computer, tablet or smartphone. 
https://example.com/join/50263834 

You can also dial in using your phone. 
Australia: +61 2 9037 3201 

Access Code: 204-761-833 

More phone numbers 
United States: +1 (571) 417-3429 
Austria: +43 7 1081 5425 
Belgium: +32 28 92 6018 
Canada: +1 (647) 467-9333 
Denmark: +45 32 72 01 62 
Finland: +358 523 16 0568 
France: +33 159 950 514 
Germany: +49 692 5536 7287 
Ireland: +353 12 360 548 
Italy: +39 0 237 92 48 01 
Netherlands: +31 107 841 377 
New Zealand: +64 9 260 6012 
Norway: +47 21 09 36 51 
Spain: +34 972 75 2103 
Sweden: +46 253 098 826 
Switzerland: +41 225 3290 67
United Kingdom: +44 17 3515 4021 

First Meeting? Let's do a quick system check: https://example.com/system-check
```

I would like to match the regex in the order that it is written. That would mean, if United States is first, return its match, if Australia is first return its match.

At the moment, whatever shows up first in the string is what is matched. In the above example that would be Australia.

Is there a way I can return the match that is earliest on my priority list in the regex?

Comment: The easiest way would just be to perform multiple searches. First, search for occurrences of `United States`. If none is found, search for occurrences of `Australia`. And so on.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping there was a nicer way to do it. That's what I have at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: No, a regex pattern returns always the first succeeding position in a string. You can put `.*` before each alternative with the m modifier, but this way isn't very efficient.

Comment: You can eventually do that: http://rubular.com/r/LTYp77ARZM

Comment: There appears to be an error in that regex @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Why does your regex contains references to several countries if you only want to match the first? If, for example, you want to match "United States", why isn't the regex just `/?<country>United States): (?<dial_number>\+1([ ]*[()\d\-\.]+)+)/`? You can create the regex dynamically of course: country = "United States"; `/?<country>#{country}): (?<dial_number>\+1([ ]*[()\d\-\.]+)+)`.

Comment: If "that's what you have already", then **please include your code in the question!!!**

Comment: @MattHough: the pattern has been truncated, I don"t know why, this one is shorter with the same idea: http://rubular.com/r/FRsmPIJ0KL

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! If you can put that in an answer I'll accept it.

EDIT: Is it possible to get that regex to recognise the numbers in that order when they are in one string together? With html tags and things like `&nbsp` in between?

Comment: I think that Cary or wp78de approach is better (find all and sort), that's why I will let that as a comment and not write an answer. About your second question: if you want to extract something from an html document, use an html parser and helps yourself with the structure of the document.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not suitable for this kind of sorting. I am deeply convinced that you should just match all values in any order and then sort the result based on the order of a reference array.

Here's a little example:

```
matches = {"Australia"=>"+61 2 9037 3201",
           "United States"=>"+1 (571) 417-3429",
           "Canada"=>"+1 (647) 467-9333",
           "New Zealand"=>"+64 9 260 6012",
           "United Kingdom"=>"+44 17 3515 4021"}

order = ["United States",
         "Australia",
         "Canada",
         "United Kingdom",
         "New Zealand"]

puts matches.sort_by { |element| order.index(element.first) }
```

Answer (score 2):

We are given the following string.

```
str=<<BITTER_END
Test Meeting 
Mon, Jan 15, 2018 10:00 AM - 5:00 PM AEST 

Please join my meeting from your computer, tablet or smartphone. 
https://example.com/join/50263834 

You can also dial in using your phone. 
Australia: +61 2 9037 3201 

Access Code: 204-761-833 

More phone numbers 
United States: +1 (571) 417-3429 
Austria: +43 7 1081 5425 
Belgium: +32 28 92 6018 
Canada: +1 (647) 467-9333 
Denmark: +45 32 72 01 62 
Finland: +358 523 16 0568 
France: +33 159 950 514 
Germany: +49 692 5536 7287 
Ireland: +353 12 360 548 
Italy: +39 0 237 92 48 01 
Netherlands: +31 107 841 377 
New Zealand: +64 9 260 6012 
Norway: +47 21 09 36 51 
Spain: +34 972 75 2103 
Sweden: +46 253 098 826 
Switzerland: +41 225 3290 67
United Kingdom: +44 17 3515 4021

First Meeting? Let's do a quick system check: https://example.com/system-check
BITTER_END
```

I would be inclined to first create a hash from this string whose keys are country names and whose values are telephone numbers.

```
r = /
    ^                     # match start of line
    (?<country>[\p{L} ]+) # match >= 1 letters and spaces in named group country
    :[ ]+                 # match a colon and >= 1 spaces
    (?<dial_number>       # begin a named group dial_mumber
      \+                  # match a literal +
      (?:                 # begin a non-capture group
        # US and Canada
        1[ ]+             # match 1 followed by >= 1 spaces
        \(\d{3}\)         # match a left paren, 3 digits, a right paren
        [ ]+              # match >= 1 spaces
        \d{3}\-\d{4}      # match 3 digits, a dash and 4 digits
        |                 # or
        # rest of world
        \d{2,3}           # match 2 or 3 digits
        (?:               # begin a non-capture group
          [ ]+            # match >=1 spaces
          \d{1,4}         # match 1 to 4 digits
        ){3,5}            # close non-capture group and perform 3-5 times
      )                   # close non-capture group
    )                     # close named group dial_number
    /x                    # free-spacing regex definition mode

h = str.each_line.with_object({}) do |line, h|
  m = line.match r
  h[m[:country]] = m[:dial_number] unless m.nil?
end
  #=> {"Australia"=>"+61 2 9037 3201", "United States"=>"+1 (571) 417-3429",
  #    "Austria"=>"+43 7 1081 5425", "Belgium"=>"+32 28 92 6018",
  #    ...
  #    "Switzerland"=>"+41 225 3290 67", "United Kingdom"=>"+44 17 3515 4021"}
```

Then we could retrieve telephone numbers in the usual way.

```
h["United States"]
  #=> "+1 (571) 417-3429"

h["Shangri-La"]
  #=> nil
```

If you have a priority list of countries and want to find the first which is a key in `h`, and retrieve its telephone number, do the following.

```
priority = ["Fiji", "Shangri-La", "United States", "Finland"]

country = priority.find { |country| h.key?(country) }
  #=> "United States"
country ? [country, h[country]] : nil
  #=> ["United States", "+1 (571) 417-3429"]
```